# Where to see the custom quick action in mac os Ventura?

Tags: automator, macos-ventura

Max Os Ventura

I have created a Quick Actions (Earlier known as Service) from Automator Utility in mac OS and it works fine too.
Now I want to make some changes in it but unable to see the newly created Quick Action file in the Automator Window

Where to see the custom quick action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick way to find your previously created quick action would be under File -> Open Recent.

The file should have saved to your user's Home directory MacSSD/Users/[Username]/Library/Services. You can see this location listed if you Command+Click (or two-finger click) on an open files name listed in the window title bar.

Comment: Thanks. it helped a lot. 
when we find *Automator* through Spotlight Search, it opens some Automator.app location opens which being refred from iCloud location in side bar but when we click on Automator Icon displaying in dock , Then it opnes the Automator app window Finally. additionaly the loction of original action file can be found on **/System/Library/Automator/<whatever file name>.action**